# Unity, Visual Effects Graph - how can I programatically play + stop an effect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use the `Visual Effect Graph` to make a particle explosion.  I am trying to activate and stop this explosion programmatically.

I first create a `Particles` prefab object, and attach a `Visual Effect` Graph object to it:

[image: img1]

Then I make the `spawn rate` an `exposed parameter`.  So when the explosion activates it will set this parameter to 100.  To stop the explosion, the spawn rate will be set to 0:

[image: img2]

Now this parameter is visible in the particle prefab:

[image: img3]

Then I instantiate the Particles prefab:

```
var effect = Instantiate(particlesPrefab, position), Quaternion.identity);
```

The particle effect shows up on the screen, but the problem is **I can't find the `spawn rate` attribute.**

How can I programmatically change this attribute's value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Get the `VisualEffect` from the `Particles` `GameObject`:

   ```
   // In a MonoBehaviour attached to the Particles GameObject

   using UnityEngine.Experimental.VFX;

   ...

   // As a field in the MonoBehaviour
   public VisualEffect myEffect;

   ... 

   myEffect = GetComponent<VisualEffect>();
   ```
2. Use `SetInt` to set the exposed integer called `"spawn rate"`:

   ```
   // As class field

   public static readonly string SPAWN_RATE_NAME = "spawn rate";

   // Wherever you want to stop explosion

   myEffect.SetInt(SPAWN_RATE_NAME, 0);

   // Wherever you want to start explosion

   myEffect.SetInt(SPAWN_RATE_NAME, 100);
   ```

Comment: Unity doesn't seem to recognize the VisualEffect type.  Is there a library I need to include? 

(version: 2018.3.0f2)

Comment: You have to include `using UnityEngine.Experimental.VFX;` to reference the `VisualEffect` class.

Comment: Following the above instructions:  I get an error: `Value of name 'spawn rate' was not found  - UnityEngine.Experimental.VFX.VisualEffect:SetInt(String, Int32)`

Comment: Is the parameter still an `int` called `spawn rate`? Also, is there only one `VisualEffect` on the gameobject?

Comment: Yep, it is as I described it in the original post.

Comment: @T1000 make sure you are properly assigning the visual effect that has the `spawn rate` parameter. Here is another way: Remove `myEffect = GetComponent<VisualEffect>();`.  Make `myEffect` a `public` field of the `MonoBehaviour`. Then in the editor, drag the Visual Effect component into the exposed `myEffect` box.

Comment: I got it working.  I don't know why it didn't work before.  Thanks!